# Changing imageview size with CountDownTimer

Tags: android

I want the ImageView to change size, when the activity starts, but i want it to change smooth and tried to use timer, but faced a problem, so the code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    tapImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tapObject);

    CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            imageWidth = imageWidth + 50;
            changeSize(imageWidth);
            int imageStats = tapImage.getWidth();
            Log.d("IMAGE", String.valueOf(imageStats));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("done", "done");
        }
    }.start();
}

public void changeSize(int widthSize) {
    tapImage.getLayoutParams().width = widthSize;
}

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tapObject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/object"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="checkTap"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Problem is it changes only once and then it is not changing anymore in log i see such picture:

D/IMAGE: 150

D/IMAGE: 150

D/IMAGE: 150

D/IMAGE: 150

D/IMAGE: 150

D/IMAGE: 150

D/done: done.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke `tapImage.requestLayoutParams()` in changeSize()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void onTick(long l) {
        imageWidth = imageWidth + 50;
        changeSize(imageWidth);
        tapImage.postInvalidate();
        int imageStats = tapImage.getWidth();
        Log.d("IMAGE", String.valueOf(imageStats));

    }
```